# Implementation of a basic DataLogger

Tags: java, synchronization

In my code I have an object called `DataLogger`. As the name says it's responsible for logging data into a File.

The skeleton of the class looks like this:

```
class DataLogger {

   private BufferedWriter mFileWriter = ...
   private boolean mRunning = false;

   //constructor
   public DataLogger() {
   //init stuff
   }

   public void onEvent(..) {
   //...
   if(mRunning) {
      mFileWriter.write(...);
   }
   /...
   }

   public void start() {
   //startdata logging
   mRunning = true;
   }

   public void stop() {
   //stop data logging
   mRunning = false;
   //closing File writer etc.
   }
}
```

So the object receives `Events` in the `onEvent` method. Every time a new event comes in, the data will be logged into a file. The data logger should be started with the `start()` method and stopped with the `stop()` method. The problem I see with this code is, that if the client / caller of the DataLogger calls `stop()` it can be the case that an event just arrived at the same moment which will then be logged, although the user has called `stop()` before. This can lead even to a crash if the data stream is already closed. I guess I need to add some synchornization / Locking code here is this right? What's the best way to extend my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward solution is to synchronize both onEvent() and stop().  That way only one of the two methods may be invoked at the same time, solving your initial problem.

```
public void onEvent(..) {
public void start() {
public void stop() {
```

becomes

```
public synchronized void onEvent(..) {
public synchronized void start() {
public synchronized void stop() {
```